# What Qt widgets should be used for sprite animation viewer

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I'm looking to make a sprite animation editor. I have the loading of my custom animation file done but now need to get the actual ui started. I'm really just stuck on what widgets I would use to actually play my animation. I need to be able to go to certain frame, play, pause, loop, etc. Once I'm done with the viewing portion I plan on adding in the editing.

I've seen [AnimatedSprite](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedsprite.html) in qt docs but that seems to only allow playback of sprites in the same file. In my situation sprites can be from multiple image files and sometimes doesn't follow a grid like sprite cutter.

Comment: Your current problem is broad, and that's off-topic in SO. I recommend improving the description of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should decide whether you want to use QML or Widgets. `AnimatedSprite` is QML related class. All widget-related classes starts with "Q" letter.

If you decide to use Qt Widgets, I would recommend to take a look at [Qt Animation Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html) in combination with [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html). Most likely it will not let you do everything you want out of box, but it should provide you with a rich set of useful tools.

If you need here are [some examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-animation.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`QMovie`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html). This class may provide all the methods you need, as long as you only want to use it for viewing. The `QMovie` can be passed to a `QLabel` to show the animation.

QMovie however supports only gif out of the box (and there is a third party plugin for apng files). You would probably have to create your own image handle plugin to support your format.

If thats not applicable or to complicated, you will most likely have to create your own custom widget. Have a look at the [painter example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html). Playing an animation is not that hard if you have all the frames. A simple  `QTimer` to change the image to be drawn in a constant rate should work.